# How to add an IP alias on a bridged interface?

Tags: networking

I need to add an alias (`10.0.2.254/24`) to my bridged interfaces on my Ubuntu Server.

My `/etc/network/interfaces` is:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.200.108
        netmask 255.255.0.0
        gateway 192.168.200.254
        bridge_ports    eth0
        bridge_stp      off
        bridge_maxwait  0
        bridge_fd       0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Add the next lines to your `br0` configuration (e.g. after `bridge_fd 0`):

```
up /sbin/ip addr add 10.0.2.254/24 dev br0
down /sbin/ip addr del 10.0.2.254/24 dev br0
```

When the interface is brought up, the IP address 10.0.2.254 is added to device br0. Similarly, the address is removed when the interface goes down.