# How do I set an extra IP for an existing interface?

Tags: server, networking

I have an interface `eth0`, and I wish to give it an extra virtual IP. I achieve this by the following:

```
ifconfig eth0:0 ip.address.goes.here netmask subnet.address.goes.here
```

This works fine, however, when I reboot, this is lost.

I have tried editing `/etc/network/interfaces` to add the following:

```
auto eth0:0 iface eth0:0 inet static
    address ip.address.goes.here
    netmask subnet.address.goes.here
```

However, upon rebooting, the static ip for eth0 is loaded fine, but, the eth0:0 virtual IP is not loaded at all.

So, how can I permanently add the `eth0:0` virtual IP?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/45086/how-to-add-an-ip-alias-on-a-bridged-interface .. this is for a bridge, but change br0 to eth0 and the method is the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of that `eth0:0` business, you should do this:

- Configure your (one) static IP address in `/etc/network/interfaces` as you normally would:

  ```
  # The primary network interface
  auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.0.201
  network 192.168.0.0
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  broadcast 192.168.0.255
  gateway 192.168.0.1
  ```
- Add another IP to *this* interface by adding this right after the above:

  ```
  up /sbin/ip addr add 192.168.0.203/24 dev eth0
  down /sbin/ip addr del 192.168.0.203/24 dev eth0
  ```
- The complete file should [look *like* this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/751425/)

Now, if you check what IP addresses are configured by running `ip addr show`, both will show up:

```
2: eth0:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:1d:fa:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.201/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
    inet 192.168.0.203/24 scope global secondary eth0
```

My thanks to Lekensteyn for pointing me in the right direction. Every site on the internet just talks about `eth0:0` for a secondary IP address. *This* seems like the proper way to do it.

Comment: Yes, ifconfig has been deprecated in favour of the `iproute2` suite (the ip command). `ifconfig` will never leave my muscle memory though. Also **important** of note, `ifconfig` cannot see address aliases added by `iproute2`! (this doesn't make them work any less well).

Comment: Great! @Caesium that's along the lines of what I suspected. Good to know I wasn't completely misremembering. :)

Comment: @Caesium I am a little confused, I tried manually typing  "ip addr add 192.168.0.40/24 dev eth0 label eth0:51" which is garbage information - and, it showed up in ifconfig just fine? ... Don't suppose you fancy coming in to chat to talk a little more!?

Comment: @wilhil, ooh! you taught me something, if you add a label it *does* show up in ifconfig! If you don't use a label it doesn't. Thanks :)

Comment: The pastebin entry posted is no longer available: `The Paste you are looking for does not currently exist.`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do things the "traditional" way, the relevant part of `/etc/network/interfaces` should look like:

```
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
    address ip.address.goes.here
    netmask subnet.address.goes.here
```

instead of this, where you made a mistake:

```
auto eth0:0 iface eth0:0 inet static
    address ip.address.goes.here
    netmask subnet.address.goes.here
```

Comment: After adding, execute: `ifup eth0:0` to start it manually.  You can check if its working by executing: `netstat -rn`